# Detect checked event after fontawesome changes radiobutton into svg element

Tags: font-awesome-5

Font-Awesome 5 has svg support, but it changes my `radiobutton` into a svg element, and therefore I don't know how to get the `onchange` event.  In the DOM if you inspect the radio buttons it looks like `<svg ... >` not `<input ... >`

HTML

```
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-slN8GvtUJGnv6ca26v8EzVaR9DC58QEwsIk9q1QXdCU8Yu8ck/tL/5szYlBbqmS+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<input id="radio1" type="radio" name="radio" class='fas fa-star fa-2x' > 
<input id="radio2" type="radio" name="radio" class='fas fa-star fa-2x' > 
<input id="radio3" type="radio" name="radio" class='fas fa-star fa-2x' > 
<input id="radio4" type="radio" name="radio" class='fas fa-star fa-2x' >
```

CSS

```
.svg-inline--fa 
{
  color : red;
}


.svg-inline--fa:hover
{
  color : blue;
}

.svg-inline--fa:checked
{
  color : yellow; /* does not work */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/patrickinminneapolis/45pLwrvz/44/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use separate elements for the icon and the radio input.

```
<label class="radio" for="rating1">
   <i class='fas fa-star'></i>
   <input type="radio" value=1 name="rating" id='rating1' style='display: none;'>
</label>
```

The input may be visually hidden, but clicking the label which contains the icon, is like click the input

Comment: I'm not going to be able to catch the radiobutton change event if the radiobutton is hidden

Comment: Actually using the for attribute on the label I am able to catch the change event and post Ajax calls. Have tried it and it did not work?

Comment: I was trying to catch the 'checked' event but I should have been catching the 'onchange' event